# Como ler variável de outro programa?

Tags: c, python

Galera, estou aprendendo Programação e gostaria de saber: como faço para meu programa ler o valor de uma variável de outro programa (teoricamente isso seria sem "consciência" do programa lido, não sei exatamente como isso funciona, se teria que pedir alguma permissão... Algo como faz o Cheat Engine, só que sem atribuição, só leitura mesmo)?
Tenho o básico (bem básico mesmo, conclui apenas a disciplina de Intro a Computação na minha faculdade) de Python, C e arrisco um pouco em C++ e Java

Comment: Se você quer fazer comunicação entre os dois programas, você pode utilizar *sockets* de rede.

Answer (score 8):

Lamento informar que só com conhecimento básico você não vai conseguir fazer isso - até com conhecimento avançado isso não é trivial. Você precisa de alguma forma entrar no espaço do processo do outro programa, aprender ou descobrir como as suas estruturas de dados estão definidas da memória, saber o **local** e o **tempo** exato em que deve ler a memória do programa, e mapear a informação lida no seu conceito de "variável".

Tem muitas outras considerações. Por exemplo, depende bastante do ambiente em que o programa está rodando. O seu programa é um app de telefone (iOS / Android / WinPhone) ou tablets (iOS / Android / Windows)? Sem chance - o sistema operacional isola os apps de forma que eles não têm acesso aos outros aplicativos. É uma aplicação desktop (Windows ou Mac)? O seu programa teria que ter acesso ao espaço de memória virtual do outro programa, o que não é o caso na maioria das vezes (pode ser que você precise usar um *driver* (mais uma tarefa com certeza não trivial) para conseguir acesso ao espaço de memória do outro processo).

Ok, assumindo que você consiga a um certo momento ler toda a memória do outro programa (como eu disse acima, não é uma hipótese provável). Que tipo de variável você quer ler? Se for uma variável local de um método, ela estará alocada na pilha de execução do programa, então você terá que acessar a memória exatamente no momento em que aquela função está sendo executada, e saber dentro da pilha qual valor corresponde à variável que você quer (outra tarefa não trivial). Outra coisa: pode ser que a variável represente não um valor primitivo, mas um objeto - que está armazenado não na pilha, mas sim no *heap* de objetos (o que acontece quando você usa o `new` em Java, por exemplo). Então na pilha você terá apenas o endereço do espaço de memória onde está o valor da variável. E aquele valor pode mudar - em Java ou C#, quando o *garbage collector* rodar, o objeto tem chances de ser movido.

Enfim, se você quer hackear um outro programa, tentar obter o valor de uma de suas variáveis não é o melhor caminho :)

Comment: O programa que eu estava em mente seria para Windows... Achei que fosse mais simples, já que o próprio Cheat Engine se adéqua a Desktops com uma certa facilidade (nunca precisei configurar nada ou instalar drivers) e acredito eu que a variável não seja global, pois estou tentando tirar valores de um emulador (que varia de acordo com o jogo), mas acredito que a função que a possua esteja sendo executada o tempo todo durante a jogatina.

Comment: Só a título de esclarecimento, minha intenção não era hackear um programa, mas apenas pegar esses parâmetros que são meio "subjetivos" no jogo e transformar ele em algo visível para o usuário :) EDIT: não sei se isso se enquadra no que é discutível aqui, mas sabe se teria como incorporar o próprio Cheat Engine em um programa?

Comment: Um *cheat engine* é uma forma de hacking :). Eu não sei como os CE funcionam internamente, mas imagino que eles sejam configurados para programas específicos de forma que eles sabem como o programa é compilado, e pode alterar o código binário de acordo com os *cheats* que ele quer aplicar - e não acessando as variáveis do programa não modificado dinamicamente.

Answer (score 3):

Bem como já foi dito é algo meio complexo (desculpas carlosfigueira, mais você exagerou um pouco não é tão difícil assim, se ele já trabalhou com C, deve entender bem como funciona o sistema de alocação e estrutura de dados na memoria, claro que supondo que ele realmente aprendeu bem C, e não somente 'hello world') mais não impossível...

Se for no SO windows você pode estudar a DLL 'kernel32.dll', do próprio windows, que trata deste assunto, mais especificamente as seguintes funções : 'OpenProcess', 'ReadProcessMemory' e 'WriteProcessMemory';

Também pode procurar uma biblioteca pronta com estas funções abstratizadas pra linguagem que você estiver trabalhando.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Diogo Rosa de Matos,  estou entrando em um novo projeto na empresa em que trabalho agora, e estamos trabalhando com engenharia reversa para um novo programa. ESTE vai ser usado para sistemas de testes de seguranca!   Bom... meu ponto eh.. **por favor.. precisamos de respostas.. de como resolver o problema exposto**.  NUNCA  de negativas ou de **voce nao deve fazer isso porque blablabla** O uso e cuidados legais eh pela conta do usuario...  neh?   BOM nessa... de nao dar a resposta para um "possivel" hacker de todinho eu ficaria sem a informacao. Obrigado mais uma vez!!

Comment: Eu não disse que era impossível, só não trivial. Ler a *memória* de um programa não é difícil (vide as funções do kernel mencionados pelo @Diogo). Mas a pergunta era sobre acessar **variáveis específicas** - isso implica que você precisa saber como a memória do programa está estruturada num certo momento. Essa é a parte que não é trivial (memória pode ser movida, por exemplo via *garbage collection*, entre outras coisas).

Answer (score 0):

Estou procurando a mesma resposta e esse foi o mais perto que cheguei até o momento:

getenv
char * getenv (const char * nome);
Obter cadeia de ambiente
Recupera uma string C contendo o valor da variável de ambiente cujo nome é especificado como argumento. Se a variável solicitada não fizer parte da lista de ambientes, a função retornará um ponteiro nulo.

O ponteiro retornado aponta para um bloco de memória interna, cujo conteúdo ou validade pode ser alterado por outrasgetenv(mas não por outras funções da biblioteca).

A string apontada pelo ponteiro retornado por esta função não deve ser modificada pelo programa. Alguns sistemas e implementações de bibliotecas podem permitir a mudança de variáveis ​​ambientais com funções específicas (putenv, setenv ...), mas essa funcionalidade não é portátil.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/