# Como obter o valor de uma variável da memória?

Tags: java, c, c++

Eu curso o primeiro período de CC e gostaria de saber como eu poderia conseguir valor variáveis de um jogo, por exemplo, em tempo real. Por exemplo, quando uma variável booleana mudar o valor para TRUE, eu queria ter acesso a esse estado da variável. Tem como fazer isso ? em java ? Eu teria que ter acesso ao endereço da memória dessa variável do jogo ? A dúvida surgiu porque eu preciso de um programa que tenha acesso aos dados do jogo...

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/como-ler-vari%C3%A1vel-de-outro-programa

Comment: Você tem acesso ao código-fonte do jogo e é livre para alterá-lo? O jogo é feito em qual linguagem?

Comment: Não tenho acesso, nem é livre e nem sei a linguagem kkkk, mas obrigado pelo link, deveria ter achado esse link antes de perguntar.

Answer (score 0):

As respostas no link do @bfavaretto explicam bem qual é a situação, e se você está no primeiro período de CC, ainda falta muita teoria pra você entender os detalhes envolvidos.

Tendo dito isso, o Jason Devlin tinha uma [série sobre DLL injection](https://web.archive.org/web/20080605191028/http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-i-built-a-working-poker-bot) no blog dele, aplicada a fazer um robô que jogasse poker (o site está fora do ar, mas no archive.org você consegue achar os outros posts da série). Ele postou o código do bot dele, que você pode estudar se você quiser entender como funciona o processo.

Comment: Oks, obrigado cara :)